# Excel Userform - Disable Buttons and Pages Automatically After Sucesfull Login

Tags: excel, vba

I have set a login where the person inserts their credentials and if it logs successfully, it should automatically open the userform but with some buttons and multipages disabled. I tried with and without an If statement, but still does not work. If i set it to a button, it sometimes work and sometimes does not as well...

```
Sub StartSuperv()
Load UserForm1: UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0: UserForm1.Show

'If UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
'Disable Buttons
UserForm1.inicioNR.Enabled = False
UserForm1.inicioBD.Enabled = False

'Disable Pages
'UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Enabled = False
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Enabled = False
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Enabled = False

'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `UserForm1.Show` This will open the form in `modal`. The lines after that will not execute till the form is unloaded. Move the rest of the code in `UserForm_Initialize()` or show the form in modeless. `UserForm1.Show vbmodeless`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Works! What is the difference between modal and modeless?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/showmodal-property

Comment: More links can be found if you type `modal and modeless vba` in Google :)